# argument remapping: how to find the argument name

Tags: rosnode, rosservice, remapping, rosrun, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the [UnderstandingServicesParams Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams)
I create another turtle using

`$ rosservice type spawn| rossrv show`

I can control the turtle2 by publish a topic to it directly.

`$ rostopic pub /turtle1/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]'`

but I want to use

`$ rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key`

then I can control it using my keyboard.

So I think I should do a argument remapping. There should be a argument control which turtle I want to control.(just call it  _id instead) so I can run

`$ rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key _id:=turtle2`

so I'm wondering how to find the argument's name.(i.e. what is the real name of "_id")

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128011/argument-remapping:-how-to-find-the-argument-name/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not quite sure what the topics involved here are, but you should be able to use [topic remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) to do what you're talking about, once you figure out which topic you need to remap.

I would start by looking at the topics that the turtle teleop node is publishing by running it, and running `rosnode info turtle_teleop_key` in another terminal. You should be able to find the relevant output topic; it will have type `geometry_msgs/Twist`. From there, simply run the `turtle_teleop_key` node and remap that topic your desired output topic: `/turtle1/cmd_vel`

If the current output topic is `/turlte1/cmd_vel` and the desired output topic is `/turtle2/cmd_vel`, your remapping argument would be:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/turtle2/cmd_vel
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-02-10**:
Thanks! /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/turtle2/cmd_vel is amazing!